# detect XP or windows-7 in javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I detect if my web application is running on Window XP or Windows 7 using JavaScript?

Any help / sample code would be appreciated.

Comment: May I ask *why*?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - detecting the operating system and operating system version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774560/jquery-detecting-the-operating-system-and-operating-system-version)

Comment: Use `navigator` variable properties. Such as `navigator.appVersion`, `navigator.userAgent`, `navigator.platform`. For example _"Windows NT 6.1; WOW64;"_ refer to Win7 x64 (browser runned in WOW mode).

Comment: when you feel that an answer is useful you can also upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Information about browser and OS are contained in the `navigator` object.

Just try in the two OS (win7 and winXP) a

```
window.alert(navigator.appVersion);
```

and look at the differences btw the strings in the alert popup. 
With a little parsing of such string you will be able to retrieve all info you need.

Answer (score 1):

[Understanding User Agent Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

To output the user agent of your browser, use:

```
javascript:alert(navigator.userAgent)
```

This will give you an output of something like:

```
"Windows-RSS-Platform/2.0 (MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1)"
```

If you parse the `userAgent` data for the **Platform Token** (which is `Windows NT 6.1` in the above example), you will return the version of Windows. Just take in consideration that every browser uses their own format for the `userAgent` and detecting features may be a better approach.