# jQuery - detecting the general platform Windows / Linux / Apple

Tags: jquery, operating-system, detect

This based on [jQuery - detecting the operating system and operating system version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774560/jquery-detecting-the-operating-system-and-operating-system-version)

I just want to test the platform Windows or Linux or Apple. Would that be correct?

```
var os = (function () {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
return {
        isWindows: /(windows|win95|win32|win64)/.test(ua),
        isLinux: /(linux|freebsd|ssl-mm)/.test(ua),
        isApple: /(mac os|mac_powerpc)/.test(ua)
    };
}());
```

**Test: http://jsfiddle.net/k5mGC/4/**

Is there a full list of user agent results? I only found example lists like http://user-agents.my-addr.com/user_agent_request/user_agent_examples-and-user_agent_types.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also use `navigator.appVersion`.

```
var OSName = "Unknown OS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")   != -1) OSName = "Windows";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")   != -1) OSName = "MacOS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("X11")   != -1) OSName = "UNIX";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux") != -1) OSName = "Linux";

alert("You are using " + OSName);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/k5mGC/1/)

Comment: Thanks. But that also uses the userAgent info so `Lynx/2.8.5rel.1 libwww-FM/2.14 SSL-MM/1.4.1 GNUTLS/0.8.12` would not apply to `indexOf("Linux")`

Comment: What do you mean when saying "that also uses the userAgent info"?

Comment: I ment that your version is not much safer than mine.