# How can I detect my computer specs and show it in the browser?

Tags: javascript, php, detect, specs

Is it possible to detect the computer specifications from the browser? For example to list the CPU, RAM, video hardware, etc in the browser that I'm using.

I've heard that this is impossible do in PHP because it is a server-side language, but I don't know if Javascript can do this.

Comment: As far as I know JavaScript has no API to fetch system specs. You could consider writing a browser plugin that fetches it data from an installed program.

Comment: You could do with with a Java Applet ... though of course the odds on anyone letting an unsigned Java Applet run these days ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774560/jquery-detecting-the-operating-system-and-operating-system-version

Comment: This is a clear question with a well-defined answer, not sure why the downvotes.

Answer (score 4):

There are no in-browser APIs to get system information like that.

This is for security reasons—it would be easy to use this as the basis for fingerprinting and circumventing restrictions on cookies (e.g. advertisers could easily identify your computer and you without having to use cookies).