# user agent for windows 7 vs 8 vs 10

Tags: javascript, user-agent

How can you determine whether a user is using windows version 7 or 8 or 10?

i have

```
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
var match = userAgent.match(/Trident\/(\d+[.]\d+)/);
```

That checks to see if the user is on IE 11. How can I figure out what version of windows it is using using javascript?

Comment: Did you look for answers before you asked? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514179/how-to-find-the-operating-system-version-using-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is listed in the user agent. For windows 10 it is Windows NT 10.0 for windows 8 it is 6.2, windows 8.1 it is 6.3 and windows 7 it is 6.1. For example here is my user agent for windows 10

`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0`

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774560/jquery-detecting-the-operating-system-and-operating-system-version