# SWFobject, display message for OSX 10.5 and below

Tags: javascript, flash, swfobject

Having a problem with SWFObject reporting the correct error message for users running OSX 10.5 and below. (Currently getting the "Unsupported Operating System" swf loaded with links for the user to update there flash player) The problem with this is proceeding to the default links provided causes conflict with OSX 10.5 and below since Adobe directs them to update to Flash 11. Which will not work on that os!

So what I'm trying to figure out is, IF I can detect OSX 10.5 and below with SWFobject and direct them to a 'noflash' method (ie: if you would have no flash installed to begin with).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SWFObject does not include detection for specific versions of operating systems.

You might want to look here:
[Detect exact OS version from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647969/detect-exact-os-version-from-browser)