# Detect the type of OS version in browser using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, macos, browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect exact OS version from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647969/detect-exact-os-version-from-browser)

I have been looking in different post where user is trying to get the OS version but I have not find the right solution to detect the exact OS version name.

I am working on a web application which does not work well on *MAC OS X 10.8.2 version(Lion)*. I have the auto location thing and it won't work and I am trying to get the exact version number from the client browser and navigate the code accordingly. I know that I can get the OS name using

```
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) OSName="MacOS";
```

**But what about the version name?**

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I told you , I looked at couple of post but none has right solution

Comment: OK. He just linked one that does, though. Well, sort of—it looks like the answer is "you can't", at least not reliably. A user can change their user-agent string to anything they want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var v = navigator.userAgent.match(/Mac OS X ([\d_]+)/)
if(v!=null && v[1] == "10_8_2") {
    alert("U r not support!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var matches = navigator.userAgent.match(/Mac OS X ([0-9.]+)/i);

if(matches !== null && typeof matches[1] !== 'undefined')
{
    var versionNames = { '10.0': 'Cheetah', '10.1': 'Puma', '10.2': 'Jaguar', '10.3': 'Panther', '10.4': 'Tiger', '10.5': 'Leopard', '10.6': 'Snow Leopard', '10.7': 'Lion', '10.8': 'Mountain Lion' };

    if(typeof versionNames[matches[1]] !== 'undefined')
    {
        alert(versionNames[matches[1]]);
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Unidentified Mac version');        
    }
}
else
{
    alert('You are not running Mac OS X');    
}
```

This might be what you're looking for, although this may be unreliable.

[Demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m8Yb6/).

Comment: same problem as in accepted answer (corrected): this throws a null pointer-exception: "This method returns null if no match is found." (source http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp )

Comment: @MisterHenson Thanks for that... although I improved your edit.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you look for?

```
navigator.platform
```

Comment: It will not give me the exact MAC OS version? I am looking for a particular version.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look a the navigator.useragent variable. This is not 100% reliable, but using deduction you can at least provide support for this feature in *most* cases with a little work. Older browsers may not have this value set, but the majority of newer browsers (last 5 years or so) should- and that's the majority of your users.