# Detect Computer or Mobile Device in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

When a user is visiting your site, is there a way of know what type of device they are using: computer, tablet, or mobile device? For example, when I get emails sometimes I see that it says sent via iphone; how do they know that? Any help or point me in the right direction would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: You can't.

**Long answer**:

All you have is the information in the HTTP User-Agent header, which usually contains the OS name and version.

Usually, browsers running on Mac OS and Linux send enough information to identify the exact OS. For example, here's my User-Agent header:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009030423 Ubuntu/8.10 (intrepid) Firefox/3.0.7
```

You can see that I'm running Ubuntu 8.10 Intrepid Ibex.

And here's what Firefox and Safari 4 Beta report on my MacBook Pro:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.5; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021906 Firefox/3.0.7

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_5_6; en-us) AppleWebKit/528.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Safari/528.16
```

Windows browsers, on the other hand, usually only report the OS version and not the specific package (Pro, Business, etc.):

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:x.x.x) Gecko/20041107 Firefox/x.x
```

**I did not write this awnser i copied it from: [Detect exact OS version from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647969/detect-exact-os-version-from-browser) Thanks to: Can Berk Güder**