# Assigning a different font for different Operating Systems

Tags: css, windows, macos, fonts, font-face

I currently have a question, neither google search nor Stackoverflowsearch helped.
I'm currently experiencing a few troubles with different font displaying on Macs and PCs. Now my question is: Am I able to assing a different font for Windows users than for Mac users?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be possible, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647969/detect-exact-os-version-from-browser

Comment: I think through javascript we can acheive... suppose we can create different class with different fonts. i think we can apply those classes according to OS...

Comment: Why would you do that? Which is the problem (please be specific, preferably with code and/or URL) that you expect to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use javascript :

```
if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Mac') > 0)
$('body').addClass('mac-os');
```

that will make the body take the class (mac-os)
if the user on mac

and you can add the custom font in the class