# Determine if operating system is Mac

Tags: php, user-agent

I have been doing a lot of Googling recently to try and find a simple, easy php script that will identify if the user is on a Mac or not.

I want to use this to tell users if the keyboard shortcut I am telling them is "control" or "command". I don't need to know the browser or anything, just if the computer is a Mac.

Here is an outline of what I'm asking is possible:

```
if (operating_system == Mac)
{
    echo "command";
}
else
{
    echo "control";
}
```

Comment: I know this is old, but I see only browser-related answers, and it's a simple task in CLI.  If this is CLI, you can do: "if (PHP_OS_FAMILY == 'Darwin')"   .... this will be true if MacOS, false otherwise.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Create a page: identifier.php

```
<?php
$user_agent = getenv("HTTP_USER_AGENT");

if(strpos($user_agent, "Win") !== FALSE)
$os = "Windows";
elseif(strpos($user_agent, "Mac") !== FALSE)
$os = "Mac";
?>
```

then include it on the header of your site.

After that you can use it like this:

```
<?php
if($os === "Windows")
{

}
elseif($os === "Mac")
{

} 
?>
```

Edit:

For windows phone:

```
if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), 'windows phone os') > 0) {
    $mobile_browser = 1;
  }
```

Comment: This code will detect all iOS devices as being a Mac cause they all include "like Mac OS X" in their UA. Instead, you should check for "Macintosh" instead of "Mac".

Comment: Your answer will give problem When used on Windows Phone. Windows and Windows Phone will give you same answer for Windows.

Comment: @WhiteHorse or `if(stripos($user_agent, "windows") !== false && stripos($user_agent, "phone") === false) {/*Windows computer*/} else {/*Windows phone*/}`. Play with the `if ... elseif ... else` tests however you want. Still this is not 100% accurate because there may be an `IOT` or `CE` etc. This answer is just a proof of concept.

Answer (score 7):

```
 <?php

    function getBrowserOS() { 

        $user_agent     =   $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
        $browser        =   "Unknown Browser";
        $os_platform    =   "Unknown OS Platform";

        // Get the Operating System Platform

            if (preg_match('/windows|win32/i', $user_agent)) {

                $os_platform    =   'Windows';

                if (preg_match('/windows nt 6.2/i', $user_agent)) {

                    $os_platform    .=  " 8";

                } else if (preg_match('/windows nt 6.1/i', $user_agent)) {

                    $os_platform    .=  " 7";

                } else if (preg_match('/windows nt 6.0/i', $user_agent)) {

                    $os_platform    .=  " Vista";

                } else if (preg_match('/windows nt 5.2/i', $user_agent)) {

                    $os_platform    .=  " Server 2003/XP x64";

                } else if (preg_match('/windows nt 5.1/i', $user_agent) || preg_match('/windows xp/i', $user_agent)) {

                    $os_platform    .=  " XP";

                } else if (preg_match('/windows nt 5.0/i', $user_agent)) {

                    $os_platform    .=  " 2000";

                } else if (preg_match('/windows me/i', $user_agent)) {

                    $os_platform    .=  " ME";

                } else if (preg_match('/win98/i', $user_agent)) {

                    $os_platform    .=  " 98";

                } else if (preg_match('/win95/i', $user_agent)) {

                    $os_platform    .=  " 95";

                } else if (preg_match('/win16/i', $user_agent)) {

                    $os_platform    .=  " 3.11";

                }

            } else if (preg_match('/macintosh|mac os x/i', $user_agent)) {

                $os_platform    =   'Mac';

                if (preg_match('/macintosh/i', $user_agent)) {

                    $os_platform    .=  " OS X";

                } else if (preg_match('/mac_powerpc/i', $user_agent)) {

                    $os_platform    .=  " OS 9";

                }

            } else if (preg_match('/linux/i', $user_agent)) {

                $os_platform    =   "Linux";

            }

            // Override if matched

                if (preg_match('/iphone/i', $user_agent)) {

                    $os_platform    =   "iPhone";

                } else if (preg_match('/android/i', $user_agent)) {

                    $os_platform    =   "Android";

                } else if (preg_match('/blackberry/i', $user_agent)) {

                    $os_platform    =   "BlackBerry";

                } else if (preg_match('/webos/i', $user_agent)) {

                    $os_platform    =   "Mobile";

                } else if (preg_match('/ipod/i', $user_agent)) {

                    $os_platform    =   "iPod";

                } else if (preg_match('/ipad/i', $user_agent)) {

                    $os_platform    =   "iPad";

                }

        // Get the Browser

            if (preg_match('/msie/i', $user_agent) && !preg_match('/opera/i', $user_agent)) { 

                $browser        =   "Internet Explorer"; 

            } else if (preg_match('/firefox/i', $user_agent)) { 

                $browser        =   "Firefox";

            } else if (preg_match('/chrome/i', $user_agent)) { 

                $browser        =   "Chrome";

            } else if (preg_match('/safari/i', $user_agent)) { 

                $browser        =   "Safari";

            } else if (preg_match('/opera/i', $user_agent)) { 

                $browser        =   "Opera";

            } else if (preg_match('/netscape/i', $user_agent)) { 

                $browser        =   "Netscape"; 

            } 

            // Override if matched

                if ($os_platform == "iPhone" || $os_platform == "Android" || $os_platform == "BlackBerry" || $os_platform == "Mobile" || $os_platform == "iPod" || $os_platform == "iPad") { 

                    if (preg_match('/mobile/i', $user_agent)) {

                        $browser    =   "Handheld Browser";

                    }

                }

        // Create a Data Array

            return array(
                'browser'       =>  $browser,
                'os_platform'   =>  $os_platform
            );

    } 


    $user_agent     =   getBrowserOS();

    $device_details =   "<strong>Browser: </strong>".$user_agent['browser']."<br /><strong>Operating System: </strong>".$user_agent['os_platform']."";

    print_r($device_details);

    echo("<br /><br /><br />".$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']."");

    ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function getUserOS(){
$osList = array
(
    'Windows 7' => 'windows nt 6.1',
    'Windows Vista' => 'windows nt 6.0',
    'Windows Server 2003' => 'windows nt 5.2',
    'Windows XP' => 'windows nt 5.1',
    'Windows 2000 sp1' => 'windows nt 5.01',
    'Windows 2000' => 'windows nt 5.0',
    'Windows NT 4.0' => 'windows nt 4.0',
    'Windows Me' => 'win 9x 4.9',
    'Windows 98' => 'windows 98',
    'Windows 95' => 'windows 95',
    'Windows CE' => 'windows ce',
    'Windows (version unknown)' => 'windows',
    'OpenBSD' => 'openbsd',
    'SunOS' => 'sunos',
    'Ubuntu' => 'ubuntu',
    'Linux' => '(linux)|(x11)',
    'Mac OSX Beta (Kodiak)' => 'mac os x beta',
    'Mac OSX Cheetah' => 'mac os x 10.0',
    'Mac OSX Puma' => 'mac os x 10.1',
    'Mac OSX Jaguar' => 'mac os x 10.2',
    'Mac OSX Panther' => 'mac os x 10.3',
    'Mac OSX Tiger' => 'mac os x 10.4',
    'Mac OSX Leopard' => 'mac os x 10.5',
    'Mac OSX Snow Leopard' => 'mac os x 10.6',
    'Mac OSX Lion' => 'mac os x 10.7',
    'Mac OSX (version unknown)' => 'mac os x',
    'Mac OS (classic)' => '(mac_powerpc)|(macintosh)',
    'QNX' => 'QNX',
    'BeOS' => 'beos',
    'OS2' => 'os/2',
    'SearchBot'=>'(nuhk)|(googlebot)|(yammybot)|(openbot)|(slurp)|(msnbot)|(ask jeeves/teoma)|(ia_archiver)'
);

$useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$useragent = strtolower($useragent);

foreach($osList as $os=>$match) {
    if (preg_match('/' . $match . '/i', $useragent)) {
        break;  
    }
    else
    {
        //$os = "Not automatically detected.<br />$useragent";  
        $os = "unknown";
    }
}

return $os;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this cannot *really* be done.

---

For the purpose of answering your question without going too far into why User Agent sniffing is broken here is some code that will do what you want:

```
$mactest = strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], 'Macintosh') ? true : false;

if($mactest) {
  do something
} else {
  do something else
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the [`get_browser()`](https://www.php.net/get_browser) function that's built into PHP.

```
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
echo "Platform: " . $browser["platform"] . "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for answering so fast! To tell you the truth, I'm fairly new to php. do you mind putting this into an if statement format for me? Thank you so much

Comment: Note: This will only work if browscap is set in php.ini and the browscap is also present. In my experience, that is not very common.

Comment: @user2180108 get_browser() required browsecap.ini for full functionality. This requires your administration input.. Use the URL provided to read about get_browser, and go here: http://tempdownloads.browserscap.com/   for browsecap.ini

Comment: @Ares most web providers have a version of browsecap, just depending on the version.. Most are up to date, some just leave it as it is because 'it works'

Comment: @user2180108 Well, with the current status..He's currently above this question ;)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/user_agent.html

As per [Detect exact OS version from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647969/detect-exact-os-version-from-browser)
**Short answer:** Exactly You can't.

**Long answer:**

All you have is the information in the HTTP User-Agent header, which usually contains the OS name and version.

Usually, browsers running on Mac OS and Linux send enough information to identify the exact OS. For example, here's my User-Agent header:

> Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009030423 Ubuntu/8.10 (intrepid) Firefox/3.0.7

You can see that I'm running Ubuntu 8.10 Intrepid Ibex.

And here's what Firefox and Safari 4 Beta report on my MacBook Pro:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.5; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021906 Firefox/3.0.7
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_5_6; en-us) AppleWebKit/528.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Safari/528.16

Windows browsers, on the other hand, usually only report the OS version and not the specific package (Pro, Business, etc.):

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:x.x.x) Gecko/20041107 Firefox/x.x

// this will help you

```
$uagent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "<br/>";

function os_info($uagent)
{
    // the order of this array is important
    global $uagent;
    $oses   = array(
        'Win311' => 'Win16',
        'Win95' => '(Windows 95)|(Win95)|(Windows_95)',
        'WinME' => '(Windows 98)|(Win 9x 4.90)|(Windows ME)',
        'Win98' => '(Windows 98)|(Win98)',
        'Win2000' => '(Windows NT 5.0)|(Windows 2000)',
        'WinXP' => '(Windows NT 5.1)|(Windows XP)',
        'WinServer2003' => '(Windows NT 5.2)',
        'WinVista' => '(Windows NT 6.0)',
        'Windows 7' => '(Windows NT 6.1)',
        'Windows 8' => '(Windows NT 6.2)',
        'WinNT' => '(Windows NT 4.0)|(WinNT4.0)|(WinNT)|(Windows NT)',
        'OpenBSD' => 'OpenBSD',
        'SunOS' => 'SunOS',
        'Ubuntu' => 'Ubuntu',
        'Android' => 'Android',
        'Linux' => '(Linux)|(X11)',
        'iPhone' => 'iPhone',
        'iPad' => 'iPad',
        'MacOS' => '(Mac_PowerPC)|(Macintosh)',
        'QNX' => 'QNX',
        'BeOS' => 'BeOS',
        'OS2' => 'OS/2',
        'SearchBot' => '(nuhk)|(Googlebot)|(Yammybot)|(Openbot)|(Slurp)|(MSNBot)|(Ask Jeeves/Teoma)|(ia_archiver)'
    );
    $uagent = strtolower($uagent ? $uagent : $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    foreach ($oses as $os => $pattern)
        if (preg_match('/' . $pattern . '/i', $uagent))
            return $os;
    return 'Unknown';
}
echo os_info($uagent);
```