# JavaScript to detect OS in Chrome Version 37.0.2062.94

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, os-detection

I'm developing one-page apps. The shortcut should vary from different OSs, especially Mac OS X. Others usually combine keystroke with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, but Mac combins with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>.

Until now, I tried to detect whether the OS is mac or not by this code:

```
var bMac = navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Mac') > -1;
```

This code worked well. **However, after updating the Chrome to the recent version (37.0.2062.94), it doesn't work anymore.**

Is there anyway to detect host OS of browser in JavaScript?

I checked Google Docs in Chrome and it's shortcut worked well with <kbd>Cmd</kbd> in Mac and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> in Window. There should be a way to detect OS in JavaScript in Chrome.

**EDIT**
I googled and found some pages about detecting OS in javascript:

- http://www.javascripter.net/faq/operatin.htm
- [How to detect my browser version and operating system using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219582/how-to-detect-my-browser-version-and-operating-system-using-javascript)
- (lots of more...)

Comment: navigator.userAgent ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect exact OS version from browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647969/detect-exact-os-version-from-browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there were some unexpected side effect while upgrading the version. It's still hard to understand.

When I checked the `navigator.appVersion`, it looked strange that there was `Linux; Android...`.

```
> navigator.appVersion
  "5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.2; GT-I9505 Build/JDQ39) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.59 Mobile Safari/537.36"
```

I checked the `Emulation` tab in the developer tools, and it looked like this:
[image]

It was strange that this tab was usually empty. Anyway 
after I clicked `Reset` button in the tab, it come back.

```
> navigator.appVersion
  "5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36"
```

Answer (score 0):

With `navigation.userAgent`you should good to go, but you have to parse the response. This is a very good [small javascript](https://github.com/rafaelp/css_browser_selector) to detect OS, browser, device, device version, etc. By adding classes to the `html` tag. It's intended to help you with css styles but it have other uses as well.

Example, after running that small javascript you'll have:

```
<html class="webkit chrome mac">
```